# How to exit pdb and allow program to continue?

Tags: python, pdb

I'm using the pdb module to debug a program. I'd like to understand how I can exit pdb and allow the program to continue onward to completion. The program is computationally expensive to run, so I don't want to exit without the script attempting to complete. `continue` doesn't seems to work. How can I exit pdb and continue with my program?

Comment: `continue` exits loops, `return` exits methods/functions

Comment: @Stephan: He's talking about `continue`, the pdb command. Not the Python statement.

Comment: @turtle: `continue` should "Continue execution, only stop when a breakpoint is encountered", according to the docs. Do you have a breakpoint set that is getting hit?

Comment: ah. ok i see. yep, i have a break point set inside a loop. anyway to get around this? the loop is called thousands of times, so I can't keep manually hitting continue.

Comment: @turtle: Do you have a breakpoint set from within Pdb, or do you have a `pdb.set_trace()` in your source code?

Answer (score 287, accepted):

`continue` should "Continue execution, only stop when a breakpoint is encountered", so you've got a breakpoint set somewhere. To remove the breakpoint (if you inserted it manually):

```
(Pdb) break
Num Type         Disp Enb   Where
1   breakpoint   keep yes   at /path/to/test.py:5
(Pdb) clear 1
Deleted breakpoint 1
(Pdb) continue
```

Or, if you're using `pdb.set_trace()`, you can try this (although if you're using pdb in more fancy ways, this may break things...)

```
(Pdb) pdb.set_trace = lambda: None  # This replaces the set_trace() function!
(Pdb) continue
# No more breaks!
```

Comment: The above doesn't __exit__ pdb.

Comment: @SteveBarnes: Is it supposed to?

Comment: About the 15th word of the question!

Comment: @SteveBarnes: I think you're taking it too literally. The OP is just hitting a breakpoint over and over again. All they need is to continue their long-running process without hitting breakpoints. Whether or not Pdb is actually running is inconsequential.

Comment: Nice tip on setting `set_trace = lambda: None` :)

Comment: For the extreme cases, nothing beats `set_trace = lambda: None`. Python org should add a command that just lets you get out of pdb.

Comment: For those who want set_trace to work as expected again at a later point. **reload(pdb)** Obtained from here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19098850/is-it-possible-to-remove-a-break-point-set-with-ipdb-set-trace

Comment: How will it work if I use `python 3.7` and `breakpoint()`

Answer (score 54):

A simple <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>D</kbd> will break out of pdb. If you want to continue rather than breaking, just press <kbd>c</kbd> rather than the whole `continue` command

Comment: What about when you're inside a function, inside a loop? It seems to just go to the next loop for me, and I can't actually close pdb, or even close python, without closing the entire terminal?

Comment: @LimokPalantaemon Weird, have you tried typing `exit`

Comment: This doesn't work if you set a trace or if you have break points unless you continue to press c .

Comment: embarassing, but this saved me from being stuck for too long -_-

Comment: this closes the python console too.

Answer (score 16):

The [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17820890/179332) from @voithos is correct, so I'll just add one alternative in the case where you are using `set_trace`.  Yes, the `pdb.set_trace = lambda: None` hack works OK, but not if you have other breakpoints set and want to reenable it later on.  To me this points to the fact that unfortunately `pdb` is missing a bunch of functionality (even basic stuff like display lists), and this is another case.

The good news is that [`pdb++`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pdbpp/) is a great drop-in replacement for `pdb`, and one of the things it solves is exactly the problem of disabling `set_trace`.  So you can simply do:

```
pip install pdbpp
```

and then at the `(Pdb++)` prompt, type:

```
pdb.disable()
```

If you want to reenable later, unsurprisingly this works:

```
pdb.enable()
```

Easy!  And you will get lots of other useful goodies on top of that.

Answer (score 12):

If you used `breakpoint()` in your code, you can disable all those breakpoints by environment variable.

```
import os
os.environ['PYTHONBREAKPOINT'] = '0'
```

This also work when you are in (Pdb) interactive state, this will disable all `breakpoint()` inserted in your code, but not breakpoints enabled by (Pdb).

So lets test this, code have `breakpoint()` in line 4:

```
> /tmp/py.py(5)<module>()
-> print(x,a)
(Pdb) ll
  1     
  2     for x in "abcdefg":
  3         a=1
  4         breakpoint()
  5  ->     print(x,a)
  6         b=2
  7         print(x,b)
```

Lets set new breakpoint in line 6.

```
(Pdb) break 6
Breakpoint 1 at /tmp/py.py:6

(Pdb) break
Num Type         Disp Enb   Where
1   breakpoint   keep yes   at /tmp/py.py:6
```

Now lets disable all `breakpoint()` in this case in line 4.

```
(Pdb) import os
(Pdb) os.environ['PYTHONBREAKPOINT'] = '0'
```

and continue

```
(Pdb) c
a 1
> /tmp/py.py(6)<module>()
-> b=2
(Pdb) ll
  1     
  2     for x in "abcdefg":
  3         a=1
  4         breakpoint()
  5         print(x,a)
  6 B->     b=2
  7         print(x,b)
```

now it stops in line 6 and skip line 4, lets continue

```
(Pdb) c
a 2
b 1
> /tmp/py.py(6)<module>()
-> b=2
```

now it stops again in line 6 and skip line 4

```
(Pdb) break
Num Type         Disp Enb   Where
1   breakpoint   keep yes   at /tmp/py.py:6
(Pdb) clear 1
Deleted breakpoint 1 at /tmp/py.py:6
```

now (Pdb) breakpoint in line 6 is deleted and program can continue working:

```
(Pdb) c
b 2
c 1
c 2
d 1
d 2
e 1
e 2
f 1
f 2
g 1
g 2
```

Answer (score 5):

If you really wish to exit the debugger then you need to run something like [WinPdb](http://winpdb.org/docs/) which allows you to detach from the process and then exit the debugger, (N.B. It is multi-platform).

If you would like to continue debugging but no longer stop at a given breakpoint then you need to:

1. Make a note of the breakpoint number, (or the file and line number),
2. Either `cl bp_number` *or* `clear file:line` to permanently remove the breakpoint **or** `disable pb_number` to toggle it off but be able to toggle it back.
3. Then `continue` and your program run until then next ***different*** breakpoint is hit.

For more detail on the above see [the manual](http://docs.python.org/2/library/pdb.html).

Answer (score 1):

I was stuck in a pdb shell, with Enter just producing `^M`, so I couldn't escape it.

After some scientifically-crafted experimentation, turns out `ctrl+Z` haults the pdb shell. (Then `stty sane` to fix the Enter key.)

Then you need to kill or resume the pdb shell. To do so, run `jobs`, then either `fg 1` or `kill %1` (substituting the job number).

Figured I'd note it here for any others, and myself when I'm back here next week.

Answer (score 1):

- hit `c` -> for continue (executes your program further)
- hit `q` -> for quit (exit debugger and your program as well)

Answer (score 0):

find new way to exit the pdb without install anything:
- when the program starts to run, press ctrl+c, then switch the window to another(any window), then the original shell with pdb running should show
something like: (pdb) .....
- switch back to pdb, then press Enter, now you are all set, pdb command
shell reappear again

Answer (score 0):

Disable the breakpoint. from pdb, just type disable N, where N is the breakpoint number you are stuck on. If you don't know the number of your troubling breakpoint, enter tbreak. This will list your breakpoints by number under column "Num" and show whether (yes)  or not (no) they are enabled or disabled under the column headed with "Enb."

Once you disbale your troubling breakpoint, running the command continue (or the abbreviation c) should finish your program.

Answer (score 0):

which running pdb in docker shell/container, in order to exit

run `pdb.disable()` and then `exit()`