# Is it possible to skip breakpoints in pdb / ipdb?

Tags: python, pdb, ipdb

Is there a way to tell pdb or ipdb to skip all future break-points and just finish execution as if they weren't there?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17820618/how-to-exit-pdb-and-allow-program-to-continue. I'm not sure, so not voting to close.

Comment: That "duplicate" is completely unrelated

Answer (score 9):

Maybe you can try with clear.

From help:

```
(Pdb) help clear
cl(ear) filename:lineno
cl(ear) [bpnumber [bpnumber...]]
With a space separated list of breakpoint numbers, clear
those breakpoints.  Without argument, clear all breaks (but
first ask confirmation).  With a filename:lineno argument,
clear all breaks at that line in that file.

Note that the argument is different from previous versions of
the debugger (in python distributions 1.5.1 and before) where
a linenumber was used instead of either filename:lineno or
breakpoint numbers.
```

There is another topic which discuss of your question: [How to exit pdb and allow program to continue?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17820618/how-to-exit-pdb-and-allow-program-to-continue)

Answer (score 4):

If you want to keep your breakpoints rather than clearing them, but also want them not to be reached, you can use `pdb`'s `disable` command. I don't see a convenient way to disable all breakpoints in a concise way, but you can list their numbers in the `disable` command. You can also be selective about this, and disable some breakpoints and leave others enabled. You can undo the effect of a `disable` command with `pdb`s `enable` command. The `break` command (or just `b`) with no parameters shows, for each breakpoint, whether it is enabled.