# How can I set Django `Debugger` time?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework, django-views

The Django debugger is `import pdb; pdb.set_trace()`.

Sometimes we push the code on the server without remove `debugger` from the code.

In this conditions when we request the view (that views contain `debugger`) then the page will not load and the browser will hang because of that debugger.

So my Question is.

> Can I set a `debugger` time

**OR**

> How can I avoid `debugger` after a few minutes

It's the exception case because we always check in the code but sometimes we missed it by mistake.

How can I achieve this task?

Thanks in advance

Comment: The only reasonable answer is to change your development processes so that you never ship with the debugger enabled - before shipping just do a global search for `import pdb`; or use a IDE/development environment that doesn't need that import in order to run the debugger.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using python 3.7+, you can use the builtin function [`breakpoint()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#breakpoint). The specific effect of this function can be modified by setting the environment variable [PYTHONBREAKPOINT](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONBREAKPOINT)

The default behaviour of `breakpoint()` is to use `pdb.set_trace()`, but you can use a [third party debugger](https://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonDebuggingTools) instead.

If you set `PYTHONBREAKPOINT=0`, the debugger() function will not do anything (immediately return)

If you are not using python 3.7, you can check out this question about disabling `pdf.set_trace()`
[how to disable pdb.set_trace() without stopping python program and edit the code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46166539/how-to-disable-pdb-set-trace-without-stopping-python-program-and-edit-the-code)