# How to handle script errors that call pdb?

Tags: python, debugging, pdb

We write python test scripts with long run times, so we try to enable our scripts to handle errors that arise automatically and proceed.  I have to include in my overall test flow a script that I have no control over, which initiates python debugger when it hits an error.  This results in the whole test script halting to wait for user input.

Is there a way to call a script that prevents it from falling into pdb when it hits an error, even if that script is trying to engage the debugger?

Comment: you can use, `try ... except` this is a simple tutorial for that. https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_try_except.asp

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46166539/how-to-disable-pdb-set-trace-without-stopping-python-program-and-edit-the-code has a few options that you can try.

Comment: As far as I know, I can't use a try/except loop to prevent the script I'm calling from calling pdb.set_trace() within their own error handling.  Is there something specific you're thinking of?

Comment: Regarding the other thread, `os.environ["PYTHONBREAKPOINT"] = "0"` didn't have any impact.  Guessing this only helps if the script is using breakpoint() to call pdb.

After installing pdb++, `pdb.disable()` worked in a small test function, but it doesn't work for my actual application.  Now when it halts it just shows _(Pdb++)_ instead of _(pdb)_.  So maybe the script I'm trying to handle is using something other than just `pdb.set_trace()`.